# Visual Studio 2005 : Break when a value appears

Tags: visual-studio-2005, conditional-breakpoint

I'm trying to simplify my debugging tasks and I had an idea which could increase my debugging speed. 
Suppose I have a value, say 2.8651 that appear in the code at a moment I do not know. 
I'm wondering if it was possible to create a super breakpoint which would stop at the first time one of the variable takes this value. 
I recall that I do not know which variable takes the value. 
I could know it by spending some time on the debugger but I'm lazy. 
I'm not really familiar with VBA for VS. I guess, a solution would be to create a macro which would loop along local variable at each line of the code execution. It'd stop when the condition *localVariable == 2.8651* is verified.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a super breakpoint for a block of code. There are two options to achieve what you want:

- Place a **conditional breakpoint on each line** with a variable assignment. Right-click the breakpoint and click *Condition...* to specify when it should break.
- Place a **single conditional breakpoint** in the code block and check all the required variables in the condition.

As you suggested, you can place a **single breakpoint with a macro**, by right-clicking the breakpoint and select *When Hit...*. However, I highly doubt that it's possible to control the breakpoint from the macro, so this wouldn't work.